# Adjust font features for certain font styles / weights in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, kerning

Using LuaLaTeX I want to make use of Feature Files / lua code in order to adjust the kerning of certain glyph pairs, see the MWEs below.

Since my kerning corrections may not be appropriate for the different styles/weights of a font, I'd like to know: Is it possible to only apply the corrections to a certain font style/weight, e.g. only to `\normalfont`?

MWE: Using \normalfont I want to the the glyphs "A" and "V" but not using italics.

The first version works on older versions of LuaTeX; the second is intended for newer versions, e.g. TeXLive 2016.

First version:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mykern.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature kern {
  pos \A \V -100;
} kern;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont[FeatureFile=mykern.fea,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

AV \textit{AV}

\end{document}
```

Second Version:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "ktest",
    {
        type = "kern",
        data = {
          ["A"] = { ["V"] =  -1000 },
        }
    },
    "extra kerns"
  }
}
\setmainfont[RawFeature=+ktest,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

AV \textit{AV}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `UprightFeatures` to limit the effect only to the upright fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "ktest",
    {
        type = "kern",
        data = {
          ["A"] = { ["V"] =  -1000 },
        }
    },
    "extra kerns"
  }
}

\setmainfont[UprightFeatures={RawFeature=+ktest},Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\noindent AV\par
\noindent \textit{AV}

\end{document}
```

[image]