# ebgaramond swashy Q, LaTeX vs. Lilypond

Tags: fonts, characters, opentype, ebgaramond, lilypond

I am using LaTeX (`pdflatex`) and Lilypond together for a critical music edition, using the EB Garamond typeface for both. The two programs are giving me different glyphs for "Q": LaTeX provides a regular Q and Lilypond provides a swashy Q. **I want the regular Q in both documents.** Compare the results of the MWEs below.

The font provided by the `ebgaramond` package provides a swashy Q ligature. 
The ligature is not enabled by default in the version of the font loaded by `pdflatex` with `T1` encoding. It is, apparently, enabled by default in the version of the font that Lilypond loads via `pango`. Lilypond's font loading is dependent on the system, and mine is Debian GNU/Linux v8 with Gnome v3.14.1.

Another question here ([A Big fancy "Q"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133380/a-big-fancy-q)) shows how to get the swashy Q in LaTeX (using `lualatex` and loading the font with the "Contextuals=Alternate" option). But I like the default `pdflatex` output and I don't want the swashy Q in Lilypond!

**How can I get Lilypond to load the font file without the swashy Q ligature?**

*Why this is on topic: Lilypond is loading a font provided by a LaTeX package, `ebgaramond`, but it is loading it in a different way than the way LaTeX loads it. Thus this is about the interaction of Lilypond with a LaTeX package, though not necessarily with LaTeX itself.*

### Examples

File `texquack.tex` -- compile with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Quack
\end{document}
```

File `lyquack.ly` -- compile with `lilypond`:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\header {
  title = "Quack"
  tagline = ##f
}
\paper {
  line-width=2\in
  #(define fonts
    (make-pango-font-tree
      "EB Garamond" "" ""
    (/ staff-height pt 20)))
}
\score {
    \new Staff
    <<
      \new Voice { a'1 }
      \new Lyrics \lyricmode { Quack }
    >>
}
```

LaTeX output:
[image] Lilypond output:
[image]

Comment: In my opinion, the swashy Q is nicer…

Comment: I just compiled this on my system (OS X) with a newly downloaded copy of EB Garamond in my `/Library/Fonts` folder and I get the regular Q. This shows that LilyPond is using the system version of the font not the TeX version of the font. So maybe update your font?

Comment: @AlanMunn I only have the LaTeX font in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond`; the system is configured (via `.fonts.conf`) to use the LaTeX fonts.

Comment: @AlanMunn The goal was to keep the project self-contained, needing only TeXLive, lilypond v2.18.2, and my custom class files for both programs. Since lilypond uses system fonts, my idea was that if the "system font" was really the one in the TeXLive distribution, then this would reduce platform-dependence. Apparently this hasn't worked, though.

Comment: Hmm. The problem is weirder than that. The two fonts have almost identical version numbers, so it's not the font, it's the engine. Compiling with LuaLaTeX yields the regular Q but the same document with XeLaTeX yields the swashed Q.

Comment: The problem is related to this one here: [XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX different default font features](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73171) but since LilyPond has no way to select font features, I don't think the problem is solvable by us here.

Comment: @AlanMunn Is there some way to save a copy of the font file with certain features set as default, and then put that version in Lilypond's search path?

Comment: Not that I know of. The LilyPond developers are clearly working on ways to manipulate font features in LilyPond though: http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/OpenType-Features-td186089.html  (I now think this question should be closed as off topic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXLive 2016 provides the file `EBGaramond12-Regular.otf` as part of the `ebgaramond` package.

Inspecting via `fontforge`, I can see that this file defines the `calt` "Contextual Alternatives" font feature, in which the glyph `Q` is replaced by the glyph `Q.long` in certain contexts. These are defined in the table 'calt' Contextual Alternates Lookup 95 under Contextual 0 and Contextual 1. The substitution is defined in Single Substitution Lookup Table 96 and 97.

On my Debian system, the system automatically loads the font with the `calt` feature turned on. This is why the word `Quack` renders with the `Q.long` in any program using the system font selection mechanism. It is the same in LibreOffice as in Lilypond.

XeTeX loads the `calt` feature by default, but LuaTeX does not. Perhaps this is because XeTeX uses the system font mechanisms, while LuaTeX uses its own (`luaotfload`).

Consider these examples, for *plain* XeTeX and LuaTeX. We have to add the `calt` feature to LuaTeX (`:+calt` in the font definition) to get the swashy Q. Alternately we can remove the feature in XeTeX to get the regular Q (`:-calt` in the font definition).

XeTeX (compile with `xetex`):

```
\font\ebg="EB Garamond" \ebg Quack \bye
```

LuaTeX (compile with 'luatex'):

```
\input luaotfload.sty \font\ebg="EB Garamond:+calt" \ebg Quack \bye
```

The swashy Q is not available when using `pdflatex` because the program is not loading the OpenType font at all, but rather LaTeX font metric files (etc.) that have been adapted from the OpenType font, and the long Q is apparently not included.

As @AlanMunn notes, Lilypond developers are discussing how to improve Lilypond's font selection mechanisms, including specifying OpenType font features. This is not available in the stable version 2.18.2.

TL;DR -- Possible solutions are as follows:

1. Embrace the swashy Q, and abandon `pdflatex`. Compile LaTeX portion with `xelatex` using `fontspec` defaults, or with `lualatex` selecting the `calt` feature through `fontspec`. The alternate contextuals also give a swashy italic Q and a lovely italic `es` ligature.
2. Edit the font file to change the default features (e.g., edit the lookup tables in FontForge). Possibly could be done by writing a `.fea` file, as mentioned in the `fontspec` documentation.
3. Accept variable Qs in the document. Since one is in a musical score and the other is in text, it is not as noticeable.

Comment: As to solution 2, note that, if you are using lualatex, as of 0.95 it no longer supports feature files. But you may be able to program your way around that; see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315250/adjust-font-features-for-certain-font-styles-weights-in-lualatex